# Rexex Everything after the "." but ignore "|"

Tags: regex

I have 2 variations of text string:

```
10.09.2016 | 45 Min. | SWR Fernsehen | UT
```

or

```
07.09.2016 | 57 Min. WDR Fernsehen
```

I am looking to end up with:

```
SWR Fernsehen | UT
```

and

```
WDR Fernsehen
```

This is what I have tried to get the capturing group:

```
\\.\s(.*)
```

This returns:

```
| SWR Fernsehen | UT
WDR Fernsehen
```

I cant work out how to say " take everything after the "." but ignore the "|"

any ideas?

Comment: Which programming language? You could very easily split on the `|` and take the third and fourth part.

Comment: This is within import.io which I believe is javascript based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
.*\.(?:\s*\|)?\s*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uA8dA4/2)

The `.*\.`  will match up to and including the last `.` (because `*` is a greedy quantifier), `(?:\s*\|)?` will match one or zero sequences of 0+ whitespaces + `|`, `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces and `(.*)` will grab the rest into Group 1, just access this group contents with the tool/language features.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and demo - this really helps my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\.[|\s]*([^.]+)$` to get everything after the last dot, omitting the possible spaces and | at the start.

For example in Javascript:

```
str.match(/\.[|\s]*([^.]+)$/)[1]
```

gives you the desired part. If you're unsure whether it matches, start by checking `str.match(/\.[|\s]*([^.]+)$/)` isn't `null`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
\b((?:SWR|WDR).+)
```

This returns both `SWR Fernsehen | UT` and `WDR Fernsehen`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aT5dR9/1).

Comment: SWR and WDR are German TV channels, there are more than these two.

Comment: @modiX: Das weiß ich auch :)

Comment: Works for the 2 channels yes, but I was looking for more of a general solution, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

`\.(\s|\s\|\s)(.*)`

Or

`\.(\s(.*)|\s\|\s(.*))`